# Form WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages aren't captured in WndProc

Tags: c#, wndproc, windows-messages

Form keydown and keyup messages aren't captured:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            log("down");
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            log("up");
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should override [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

This example is extracted [from this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315035617/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320584)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    Keys lastKeyPressed = Keys.None;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += (s, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) 
    {
        if(m.Msg == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Filter -> KeyUp LastKeyPressed=" + lastKeyPressed.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            lastKeyPressed = keyData;
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Down:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Down Arrow Captured");
                    break;

                case Keys.Up:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Up Arrow Captured");
                    break;

                case Keys.Tab:
                    Debug.WriteLine("Tab Key Captured");
                    break;

                case Keys.Control | Keys.M:
                    Debug.WriteLine("<CTRL> + M Captured");
                    break;

                case Keys.Alt | Keys.Z:
                    Debug.WriteLine("<ALT> + Z Captured");
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Probably there is a way to extract the KeyCode from the message passed to the PreFilterMessage as explained in [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/Jaggi/archive/2006/02/02/67999.aspx)

Comment: It does not catch WM_KEYUP messages and triggers on key auto-repeat.

Comment: Not near PC now to test. but do you add wm-keyup const?

Comment: Yes, I added it. Btw many developers complain there is no WM_KEYUP reaction, but I haven't seen any solution.

Comment: I have put together some code from other answers, you need to implement IMessageFilter as explained by @HansPassant [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434834/processcmdkey-wait-for-keyup) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468200/key-events-processcmdkey).