# Detecting multiple keypresses in c#

Tags: c#

This is my program:

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        points++;
        textbox1.Text = points.ToString();
        textbox1.Refresh();
    }
```

I want the program to increase a variable everytime a key is pressed, it doesn't matter which one.

Right now my progam doesn't even start the event when i press a key, so i don't know what to do.

Comment: Try changing Form's `KeyPreview` to true

Comment: Try to override WndProc and catch every message that contains key infromation

Comment: That will only detect keypress when your form is selected. You also don't need to refresh the textbox.

Comment: I don't think that duplicate match. OP doesn't want to detect combinations of keys pressed, just increase a variable when any key is pressed. And overriding WndProc seems a bit overcomplicated for what it seems OP wants...

Comment: Now that's a duplicate that may apply...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    if(m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN || m.Msg == WM_KEYUP){
        points++;
        textbox1.Text = points.ToString();
        textbox1.Refresh();
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried it? I did and it does not work.See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408071/form-wm-keydown-and-wm-keyup-messages-arent-captured-in-wndproc)

Comment: I tried and it worked for my case. It's hard to gues why @Jacklta has problem judging only by his code and description.