# Application-wide message handler in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi, handler, windows-messages

In Delphi 6 I could set an application-wide message handler:

```
procedure TFrmMain.TntFormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnMessage:=AppMsgHandler;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.AppMsgHandler(var Msg:TMsg; var Handled:Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message=WM_KEYDOWN then begin
    ..............
  end;
  if Msg.message=WM_KEYUP then begin
    ..............
  end;
end;
```

This handler makes possible handling of keyboard events regardless which control or even which form of the application is active. Note that it is not a global system-wide keyboard hook and therefore is not so dangerous.

Now the question: How could be the same done in C# WinForms application?

I could override `WndProc` of a form but this solution does not catch any keydown and keyup events.

I could also override `ProcessCmdKey` of a form but it does not catch `WM_KEYUP`.

Also both of the solutions are applied to one form class only and I need an application-wide solution.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question and tags. WPF would be different. Like I said I think it is ProcessCmdKey for you.

Comment: @David Heffernan: how to make `ProcessCmdKey` handle `WM_KEYUP` ?

Comment: @Paul - take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434834/processcmdkey-wait-for-keyup); most especially, the answer from Hans Passant.

Comment: @Brian - beat me to it.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: Somebody should write an answer please

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Done; and I have given the credit where it is due.

Comment: @Brian Thatls not an answer. It's a collection of links. I meant a real answer which contained the crucial information right here. By all mean include links, but the main info needs to be here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -  I will remove my answer then.  I have never used `ProcessCmdKey` so, I would just be using cut-and-paste on others' code.

Comment: The point is not to use ProcessCmdKey and use a message filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Application.AddMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) to register a message filter. From the documentation:

> Use a message filter to prevent specific events from being
>   raised or to perform special operations for an event before it
>   is passed to an event handler. Message filters are unique to a
>   specific thread.
>
> To prevent a message from being dispatched, the value parameter instance that you pass to this method must
>   override the PreFilterMessage method with the code to handle the message. The method must return false.

This offers exactly the same functionality as Delphi's OnMessage event.